# PyCharm prompts with "Edit configuration" before running scratch files

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a simple Python scratch file created in PyCharm. (`File → New Scratch File → Python`)

[image: Scratch file for "Hello, world!"]

Whenever I try running my scratch file with `Run → Run... → scratch`, I get a popup window asking me to edit my configuration. If I dismiss the window and click "Run", I'm shown a popup error with "[*Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again?*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0dbb.png)"

I can run normal Python projects using Python 3.6 without any issues. It's only scratch files which prompt me to change my configuration.

Why can't I run Python scratch files in PyCharm? What's wrong with my configuration?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, Just managed to run a scratch file in PyCharm 2017.2 python 3.6. Which version of pycharm is this?

Comment: Your python interpreter isn't set. What happens when you click that dropdown box?

Comment: @FHTMitchell The issue was not having an interpreter selected. The scratch file ran without issue after selecting “Python 3.6” in the dropdown.

Comment: maybe try to configure the global interpreter